# how to asyncronously fill each content on grid view like on instagram profile

Tags: android, ios, flutter, instagram

how to asyncronously fill each content on grid view like on instagram profile on flutter. please take a look on gif below

[image]

it's like stream each card and set the content each card placeholder asycronously make the app smoothly displaying the content. thanks for help

Comment: I think your question is answered here [What is best practices for implement a infinite scroll GridView in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61708445/9941412)

Answer (score 1):

To create a grid view in Flutter that resembles Instagram's layout, you can use the    **`flutter_staggered_grid_view`**    package. This package allows you to create a staggered grid view with varying container sizes and ratios, making it suitable for Instagram-like grids.

Here's a brief guide on how to achieve this:

Install the flutter_staggered_grid_view package by adding it to your pubspec.yaml file.

Import the package in your Dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';
```

Use the StaggeredGridView.countBuilder widget to build your grid view. You can set the number of columns and provide an item builder function to asynchronously load content. For example:

```
StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
  crossAxisCount: 3, // Number of columns
  itemCount: yourItemList.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    // Your asynchronous content loading logic for each grid item
    return YourGridItemWidget(item: yourItemList[index]);
  },
  staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) => StaggeredTile.fit(1), // Tile size
)
```

Customize the appearance of your grid items as needed. You can use various widgets to display images and text in each grid item.

This will create a staggered grid view with asynchronously loaded content, similar to Instagram's grid layout.

Answer (score 0):

For these types of list i would use `ListView.builder`. The reason is this: "This constructor is appropriate for list views with a large (or infinite) number of children because the builder is called only for those children that are actually visible"

Source: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SmartRefresher](https://pub.dev/packages/pull_to_refresh) to implement load-more and refresh behaviors and use [CachedImageNetweork](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) for asynchronous load images